# How do I get my GridX to display

Tags: javascript, web-applications, dojo, dojo.gridx

I am not having any success in getting my `GridX` to display. I am currently getting 4 errors in firebug all pertaining to dojo.js, two `Error: scriptError` one `Error: multipleDefine` and one weird one: `GET https://localhost:8443/warfile/javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/dojo/store/templates/Grid.html 404 Not Found`

I am trying to follow this [poorly documented example from the Gridx wiki](https://github.com/oria/gridx/wiki/Create-the-Simplest-Gridx)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test GridX Widget</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/gridx-1.3/Grid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/gridx-1.3/GridCommon.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/document.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="javascript/gridx-1.3/resources/claro/Gridx.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .gridx {
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    </style>

<script>
    require([
             //Require resources.
             "dojo/store/Memory",
             "gridx/core/model/cache/Sync",
             "gridx/Grid"
         ], function(Memory, Cache, Grid){

        //Use dojo/store/Memory here
        var store = new Memory({
            data: [
                { id: 1, name: 'John', score: 130, city: 'New York', birthday: '1980/2/5'},
                { id: 2, name: 'Alice', score: 123, city: 'Washington', birthday: '1984/3/7'},
                { id: 3, name: 'Lee', score: 149, city: 'Shanghai', birthday: '1986/10/8'},
                { id: 4, name: 'Mike', score: 100, city: 'London', birthday: '1988/8/12'},
                { id: 5, name: 'Tom', score: 89, city: 'San Francisco', birthday: '1990/1/21'}
            ]
        });

        //We are using Memory store, so everything is synchronous.
        var cacheClass = "gridx/core/model/cache/Sync";

        var structure = [
                         { id: 'name', field: 'name', name: 'Name', width: '50px'},
                         { id: 'city', field: 'city', name: 'City'},
                         { id: 'score', field: 'score', name: 'Score', width: '80px'}
                     ];

             //Create grid widget.
             var grid = Grid({
                 id: 'grid',
                 cacheClass: Cache,
                 store: store,
                 structure: structure
             });

             //Put it into the DOM tree. Let's assume there's a node with id "gridContainer".
             grid.placeAt('gridContainer');

             //Start it up.
             grid.startup();
         });
</script>

</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="gridContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is that the **gridx** should be installed at the same level as **dojo**. i.e `gridx` path should be `javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/gridx-1.3`, same as dojo `javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/dojo`. Hope it works.

Comment: @frank Thank you for your comment, I moved the `gridx-1.3` folder into the `dojo-release-1.10.0` folder and updated three `gridx` paths in my `HTML` file, now I don't get anything in my browser as before and firebug shows no errors. I right clicked, viewed page source and clicked on all my src files and they all come up fine. Now what? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rick Lacy, from the dojo forums, he guided me to a working GridX. You can see the post [HERE](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/I-need-help-getting-my-gridx-test-to-work-tp4003917.html;cid=1412951207762-632). The problem was that I had `data-dojo-config="async: true"...` which means it pulls in the GridX js automatically and I was still including the GridX js files in my page which was causing my grid not to work. I simply removed these two lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/gridx-1.3/Grid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/gridx-1.3/GridCommon.js"></script>
```

I also renamed my gridx-1.3 directory to gridx to be more standardized.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code for GridX.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>GridX testing</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        /*Use claro theme.*/
        @import "javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
        @import "javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/document.css";

        /*Import the main CSS file of Gridx.*/
        @import "javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/gridx-1.3/resources/claro/Gridx.css";

        .gridx {
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>


    <!-- dojo configuration options -->
    <!-- For Package configuration refer tutorial at       http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modules/ -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            baseUrl: "/javascript/",
            tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,
            packages: [
                { name: "dojo",  location: "dojo-release-1.10.0/dojo" },
                { name: "dijit", location: "dojo-release-1.10.0/dijit" },
                { name: "dojox", location: "dojo-release-1.10.0/dojox" },
                { name: "gridx", location: "dojo-release-1.10.0/gridx-1.3" }
            ]
        };
    </script>
    <!-- third-party javascript -->
    <script src="javascript/dojo-release-1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script>
        require([
            //Require resources.
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "gridx/core/model/cache/Sync",
            "gridx/Grid"
        ], function(Memory, Cache, Grid){

            //create store......
            var store = new Memory({
                data: [
                    { id: 1, name: 'John', score: 130, city: 'New York', birthday: '1980/2/5'},
                    { id: 2, name: 'Alice', score: 123, city: 'Washington', birthday: '1984/3/7'},
                    { id: 3, name: 'Lee', score: 149, city: 'Shanghai', birthday: '1986/10/8'},
                    { id: 4, name: 'Mike', score: 100, city: 'London', birthday: '1988/8/12'},
                    { id: 5, name: 'Tom', score: 89, city: 'San Francisco', birthday: '1990/1/21'}
                ]
            });

            //create structure......
            var structure = [
                { id: 'name', field: 'name', name: 'Name', width: '50px'},
                { id: 'city', field: 'city', name: 'City'},
                { id: 'score', field: 'score', name: 'Score', width: '80px'}
            ];


            //Create grid widget.
            var grid = Grid({
                id: 'grid',
                cacheClass: Cache,
                store: store,
                structure: structure
            });

            //Put it into the DOM tree. Let's assume there's a node with id "gridContainer".
            grid.placeAt('gridContainer');

            //Start it up.
            grid.startup();
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="gridContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks frank, very grateful for your effort, but this doesn't work for me. I also tried it in IE with the same result. In firebug I get 3 of `Error:scriptError` with `dojo.js (line 15)`

Comment: I think i made a mistake. The **packages** configuration `{ name: "gridx", location: "dojo-release-1.10.0/gridx_1_3" }` should be `{ name: "gridx", location: "dojo-release-1.10.0/gridx-1.3" }` can you check if it works? it is working at my end.

Comment: Thanks again Frank, but it still isn't working for me. :| I will take a really close look at the code, I am still getting the same 3 `Error:scriptError` with `dojo.js (line 15)` Also tried in IE again with same results.

Comment: I tested it on Fireforx, IE and Chrome and it is working as expected. can you copy n paste my code without making changes and test it? There was a comma(,) at the end `{ name: "gridx", location: "dojo-release-1.10.0/gridx-1.3" }` which I have removed. The above code should work.

Comment: Can you do one thing. Can you change the name from `dojo-release-1.10.0` to `dojo_release_1_10_0` and `gridx-1.3` to `gridx_1_3` everywhere and check whether it is working? Also I am assuming that you have downloaded the source code ( dojo 1.10 and gridx 1.3) to the local machine.

Comment: frank, that didn't work either, still getting the same 3 errors. yes I have the source code downloaded and placed within my project and I can click on the src paths when I view page source and open up the correct files.

Comment: can you check a simple dojo button without any gridx components. example [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Button.html). Need to check whether dojo is working as expected.

Comment: frank, yes I have about 6 other html files with example dojo widgets - button, tabs with sub tabs (content panes), textbox, password, numberspinner, datetime picker, combobox - all working fine. I just cannot get a GridX to work!!

Comment: Yes, I was able to, I posted an answer to my question showing what I did. I simply had to remove the Gridx javascript links from my html page since I was using `data-dojo-config="async: true"` as it automatically brings in those javascript files. This solved my problem. Thanks again for all your help, I am very grateful for it!